# jquery span value selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Is it possible to find a span using jquery selector similar to selecting an input like this

```
$("input[value=boo]").parent().addClass("red");
```

I've tried with replacing value with text, content and other things without success.

Comment: Could you please share the HTML part?

Comment: "Is it possible to find a span using jquery selector similar to selecting an input like this"  So did you try replacing the word input with the word span?

Comment: lol. yes I did try that. it is not enough.

Comment: suppose my HTML is <span>$10</span> and I want to highlight the div around $10 (or every div around every $10). I won't pollute this question with the incorrect ways I tried but if you replace input with span in the above you can guess the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure thing. You can do something like `$("span[name='test']").parent().addClass("red");` or `$("span[id='test']")` and it'll work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter` method:

```
$("span").filter(function() {
     var txt = this.textContent || this.innerText;
     // var txt = $(this).text();
     return txt === 'boo';
}).parent().addClass("red");
```

Comment: thanks I'd say this is equally good so will upvote your anwser

Answer (score 0):

Suppose this is your span:

```
<span class='span-1'>Text of span.</span>
```

then:

```
$('span[class^="span"]').addClass('red');
```

Comment: thanks I believe this is a good option as well however since my spans are generated in code that I don't want to tamper with I prefer the solution posted by C.O.D.E.